# Replacing existing DB file gets error attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)

Tags: java, android

When I trying to delete the old db file and copy the new one from assets folder I'm getting the error:

```
attempt to write a read only database (code 1032)
```

It shows me my `openDatabase` method to the line:

```
mDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

I try to change it to `getWriteableDatabse`, but nothing changes((

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: did you close the db before copy?

Comment: When I change the version of my DB in constructor of my DatabaseHelper class I try to delete the old db file in OnUpgrade method like this:

`public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            mContext.deleteDatabase(DBNAME);
        }`

Should I use `db.close()` after that?

Comment: Here is my openDatabase method:
` public void openDatabase(){
        String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
        if (mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()){
            return;
        }
        mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        this.getWritableDatabase();
    }`